# Apply condition with group by

Tags: mysql, sql

I have one mysql table of following structure.
`orders ( id, order_status(number), date(timestamp));` 
Date is updated when status is changed.
Select count of all orders using `order_status`.
But one `order_status` say status id 10, should be selected based on date.

Ex: Consider status id 10 means order completed. Select count of orders with status 10 which is updated today. And all other status counts calculated without any condition.

```
count | s
------+---
2     | 1
6     | 2
8391  | 10
5     | 7
6     | 15
28    | 18
```

Answer (score 2):

Modifying the query I have added the condition for date:

```
select
       sum(1) all_orders
     , sum(case when order_status <> 10 then 1 else 0 end) as unclosed_orders
     , sum(case when order_status  = 10 AND date=DATE_FORMAT(NOW(),'%Y-%m-%d') then 1 else 0 end) as closed_orders_today
     , sum(case when order_status  = 10 AND date!=DATE_FORMAT(NOW(),'%Y-%m-%d')then 1 else 0 end) as closed_orders_past
from orders
```

Hope this helps!

**EDIT**

The Union of two query might get the output you want:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as count, order_status as s FROM orders  WHERE order_status='10' AND date=DATE_FORMAT(NOW(),'%Y-%m-%d')
UNION
SELECT COUNT(*) as count, order_status as s FROM orders  WHERE order_status!='10' GROUP BY order_status
```

1) Query returns the count with status of 10 and are placed today.

2) Query returns the count with status other than 10.

Union of both returns the count and status to get the desired output.

Comment: Thanks this is great. I need the output in the same format as mentioned in the question. Except for order_status (in  question in used column `s`) 10. order status is 10 should be calculated based on date.

Answer (score 0):

Use "**conditional aggregates**" which are `case expressions` inside an `aggregate function` e.g:

```
select
       count(*) all_orders
     , count(case when order_status  10 then id end) as unclosed_orders
     , count(case when order_status  = 10 then id end) as closed_orders
     , count(case when order_status  = 10 
                  and last_updated_date = current_date()
                  then id end) as closed_today
from your_table
```

Note: the `COUNT()` function ignores `NULL`s

You could simulate the same result using `SUM()` e.g.:

```
select
       sum(1) all_orders
     , sum(case when order_status <> 10 then 1 else 0 end) as unclosed_orders
     , sum(case when order_status  = 10 then 1 else 0 end) as closed_orders
from your_table
```

However I do prefer to use `COUNT()` if that is what the numbers represent.

Comment: I believe that using `COUNT(*)` is also more efficient (though the difference can be quite small).

Comment: Where to apply date condition?

Comment: I have used query like this: `select count(*) as count, order_status_id as s from oc_order GROUP by order_status_id`. When order_status_id = 10 it should select based on date. What query I have to use.

Comment: I added a **bold case expression** to include a sample date condition